# iterator error/conflict on Android with push_back (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I have an FMX app with a `TPanel` and a `TScrollBox`.  The code below is in a `TButton` click event and it creates a new `TChart` when clicked (clones an existing chart i'm using as template).  This works fine in Win32 and iOS, but fails to build for Android.

**If** i comment out the `myCharts.push_back(C)` it will build and run on Android but of course not add the new chart C to `myCharts` vector.

```
  TChart *C = new TChart(this);
  C->Parent = this->ScrollBox1;
  CloneChart(C, ChartTemplate, this, false);  // i have a template chart to copy from
  C->Align = TAlignLayout::Horizontal;
  C->Height = ChartTemplate->Height;
  C->Width = ChartTemplate->Width;
  C->Tag = myCharts.size();   
  C->HitTest = false;
  myCharts.push_back(C);
  ReSizeCharts(); // resize all charts to accommodate new one
```

At the top of my Unit1.cpp i define myCharts as a global vector:

```
std::vector<TChart*> myCharts;
```

When i attempt the Android build i get the following error messages and the ide opens `stl_iterator.h` and highlights a row in red:

`[bccaarm Error] stl_iterator.h(980): rvalue reference to type 'value_type' (aka 'Fmxtee::Chart::TChart*__strong') cannot bind to lvalue of type '__borland_class *isTObj<Fmxtee::Chart::TChart> __strong'(aka 'Fmxtee::Chart::TChart *__strong')`

[image: error in stl_iterator.h]

Here are my includes:

```
#include <FMXTee.Store.hpp>
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
```

I'm using 10.3.1 (Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.33219.4899).  Android SDK 25.2.5 32-bit.

Comment: I don't know why `push_back()` is invoking anything iterator-related to begin with, but the implementation of the `operator*` shown is wrong, it should not be calling `std::move()` at all. `return std::move(*_M_current);` needs to be `return *_M_current;` instead. File a bug report with Embarcadero. Do you have the same error if you use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`?

Comment: I changed that line to `myCharts.emplace_back(C)` and i get that same error on Android build.  On Win32 i get `emplace_back` is not a member of `std::vector<TChart*, std::allocator<TChart*> >'

Comment: `emplace_back()` is a C++11 feature, so you must be using the "classic" (non clang) compiler on Win32. The iOS and Android compilers are clang C++11 compilers

Comment: Thank you!  Adding the __unsafe allowed the code to run fine.  I'm assuming the only downside now is if i don't properly cleanup after using myCharts.  Also, should i delete this question since it is duplicate.

Comment: I posted a bug report - RSP-25537 with Embarcadero.