# fmx260.bpl access violation ShowMessage (FMX, Win32)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

My code adds TCharts to a TLayout and then changes the TLayout height to accommodate.  It works fine.  But, while debugging some code i found a really weird error.  I added a `ShowMessage(IntToStr(7))` and it causes an access violation in fmx260.bpl after i add the 2nd chart (not on first chart). After the first violation, simply moving mouse over the form causes another access violation.  This **only** happens in Win32, works fine on iOS and Android.

I can't understand why the `IntToStr(7)` causes this violation? I'm wondering if it could have anything to do with my use of `__unsafe` in declaring the myCharts vector.  I had to do that for [the reason shown here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233853/iterator-error-conflict-on-android-with-push-back-fmx-c)

**UPDATE**:  The errors happen with just a `ShowMessage("text")` as well.  Maybe it just has to do with ShowMessage?

Here are screen shots of the errors:

[image: fmx260.bpl access violation]

[image: second one]

Here are my declarations at top of Unit1.cpp:

```
#include "Unit1.h"
#include <FMXTee.Store.hpp>
#include <System.IOUtils.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
void AddChart(); // proto function
void ReSizeCharts(); //proto function
std::vector<__unsafe TChart*> myCharts;  // vector of charts
```

Here are my functions:

```
void AddChart()
{
  try {
      TChart *C = new TChart(Form1);
      C->Parent = Form1->Layout1;
      CloneChart(C, Form1->ChartTemplate, Form1, false);
      C->Align = TAlignLayout::Horizontal;
      C->Height = Form1->ChartTemplate->Height;
      C->Width = Form1->ChartTemplate->Width;
      C->MarginRight = 10;
      C->Tag = myCharts.size();
      C->HitTest = false;
      C->Visible = true;
      myCharts.push_back(C);    
      ReSizeCharts(); 
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(7)); // <-------this is is where ERROR occurs
      }
 catch( const Exception& e )
      {
      ShowMessage(e.Message);
      }
}
```

And...

```
void ReSizeCharts()
{
try{
   if (static_cast<int>(myCharts.size()>0)) {
     myCharts[0]->Position->Y = 0; 
     for (int i = 1; i < static_cast<int>(myCharts.size()); i++) {
     myCharts[i]->Position->Y = i*(myCharts[0]->Height); 
   }
   Form1->Layout1->Height = static_cast<int>(myCharts.size()) * Form1->ChartTemplate->Height;   // make sure Layout1 is tall enough
   }
  }
catch ( const Exception& e )
 {
  ShowMessage(e.Message);
 }
}
```

p.s. Error occurs on 10.3.1 and 10.3.2. I'm using C++ Builder.

Comment: Do you get the same error in a separate project that doesn't involve `TChart`? Have you [filed a bug report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com) yet?

Comment: No, in my project is the only time I've seen this error. I tried to build a stripped down version in a new project (with the code above and a TChart and TButton) and it works fine.  I'm not sure i can make a meaningful bug report (I'll keep at it though).  I can't reproduce it outside of this present project.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse me posting this as an answer but I'm not allowed to comment - too newb :o(

From what you have said we know that it is ShowMessage that is failing - and only in Win32 (which according to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Dialogs.ShowMessage) is synchronous , whereas it as asynchronous on the other platforms - I believe (but have not checked) that it maps to a standard Windows call).

We also know that you are debugging - so we infer that *something* is not working as you expect.

You have shown us where you call ShowMessage, but not how you arrive at those functions or what you expect.

It's normally the case that if a Widows API call has failed you have either passed in garbage (which may be provided form the Dialogs service layer in FMX) or your prgram is nt in a state to do what you're asking it to do (blockingmessage loops, not being thread safe etc.)

Two suggestions for things to check that may help you: What is the behaviour that you're trying to debug, and how might that relate to a break in what appears to be a Windows API call.  What is the state of the program when you call ShowMessage - remember that on Win32 the underlying Windows API is used for many things, but it is not (obviously) for iOS and Android.

I hope this helps ...

Comment: Hi Rob - thanks for your input.  I'm about 95% sure that this actually relates to some buggy behavoir of the Steema TChart.  After i ran into the above problems, i completely re-wrote my code to avoid using vectors (yes, bummer).  While working through that i found that some TChart calls produced access violations.  So, again, i'm pretty sure that was the real root.  I've just not circled back to verify for sure.